# How to get all the invoked/touched binaries for specific command execution?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line

I want to know all the binaries invoked for a particular command or in other way I want to know all the dependencies of current binary file. Is there any existing tool to help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## strace - trace system calls and signals
>
> In the simplest case strace runs the specified command until it exits.  It intercepts and
>          records the system calls which are called by a process and the signals which are received
>          by  a  process.   The  name  of  each system call, its arguments and its return value are
>          printed on standard error or to the file specified with the -o option.
>
> strace is a useful diagnostic, instructional, and debugging tool.  System administrators,
>          diagnosticians  and  trouble-shooters  will  find it invaluable for solving problems with
>          programs for which the source is not readily available since  they  do  not  need  to  be
>          recompiled  in  order  to trace them.  Students, hackers and the overly-curious will find
>          that a great deal can be learned about a system and its  system  calls  by  tracing  even
>          ordinary  programs.   And  programmers  will find that since system calls and signals are
>          events that happen at the user/kernel interface, a close examination of this boundary  is
>          very useful for bug isolation, sanity checking and attempting to capture race conditions.

Or if you just want to know what other packages the executable in question depends on, look up it's package with your distribution's package manager.

For example, in Debian you might use synaptic or `apt show [packagename]` and see a line something like

```
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2), libstdc++6 (>= 5)
```

---

### Edit for Windows strace

There appears to be a few Windows-equivalents for strace, see [Systrace for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows) on stackoverflow. One is [StraceNT](http://intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=StraceNT), a "System Call Tracer for Windows":

> StraceNT is a System Call Tracer for Windows. It provides similar functionality as of strace on Linux. It can trace all the calls made by a process to the imported functions from a DLL. StraceNT can be very useful in debugging and analyzing the internal working of a program.
>
> StraceNT uses IAT patching technique to trace function calls, which is quite reliable and very efficient way for tracing. It also supports filtering based on DLL name and function name and gives you a lot of control on which calls to trace and helps you to easily isolate a problem.

Comment: is there any windows equivalent for this?

Comment: I'll search the web for "strace for windows", but I'm not sure yet, the Q was only about Linux when I answered :) It might even be a completely different question if it's about Windows, it doesn't usually have "packages" or package management like Linux does